# How to import variable values from a file that is running?

Tags: python-3.x

I am running a python file, say file1, and in that, I am importing another python file, say file2, and calling one of its functions. Now, the file2 needs the value of a variable which is defined in file 1. Also, before importing file2 in file1, the value of the variable was changed during the run-time. How do I make the file `file2`, access the current value of the variable from file 1?

The content of file1 is:

```
variable = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    variable = 123
    from file2 import func1
    func1()
```

The content of file2 is:

```
from file1 import variable as var

def func1():
    print(var)
```

When I run the file1, I want the function `func1` in file2 to print 123. But it prints `None`. One way I can tackle this is by saving the content of the variable in some ordinary file when it is modified, and then retrieving it when needed. But the application in which I am using this code, the size of the variable is massive, like around 300 MB. So, I believe it won't be efficient enough to write the content of the variable in a text file, every time it is modified. How do I do this? (Any suggestions are welcome)

Comment: Why don't you just pass ``var`` in as a parameter?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That would definitely solve my problem. But just wondering, how to access runtime values of variables in some other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main script is run with the name `__main__`, not by its module name. This is also how the `if __name__ == '__main__'` check works. Importing it by its regular name creates a separate module with the regular content.

If you want to access its attributes, import it as `__main__`:

```
from __main__ import variable as var

def func1():
    print(var)
```

---

Note that importing `__main__` is fragile. On top of duplicating the module, you may end up importing a different module if your program structure changes. If you want to exchange global data, use well-defined module names:

```
# constants.py
variable = None

# file1.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import constants
    constants.variable = 123
    from file2 import func1
    func1()

# file2.py
from constants import variable as var

def func1():
    print(var)
```

---

Mandatory disclaimer: Ideally, functions do not rely on global variables. Use parameters for passing variables into functions:

```
# constants.py
variable = None

# file1.py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from file2 import func1
    func1(123)

# file2.py
from constants import variable

def func1(var=variable):
   print(var)
```

Comment: This is great. Using `__main__` sort of complicates things. The constants package is great for exchanging global data. Thanks for your inputs. I will check out more about the `constants` package to see what other features it provides.

Comment: @VighneshRaut ``constants`` is just a name I made up. Simply pick a name that is unique to your package/environment and create a module with just the variables inside.