# Python Cross file module variable modification

Tags: python, python-3.x

**A.py**:

```
X = 10
```

**B.py**:

```
import A
A.X = 100
```

**C.py**:

```
import A
Print("A.X = ",A.X)
```

If I execute `B` and then `C` , I get `A.X = 10`.
But what about the changes made by module `B` on `X`?
Why the changes are not reflecting in module `C`?

Comment: "If I execute B and then C" Do you execute them in the same process or in one? How do you do so?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55475928/how-to-import-variable-values-from-a-file-that-is-running/55476106#55476106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python scripts run in separate shells with separate process, memories, namespaces, etc. Modifying a module attribute in a script is a in-memory operation: it does not affect the file that the module was loaded from:

```
 $ python B.py
```

This will create a python process, load `B.py`, then `A.py`, and modify the dictionary corresponding to the namespace of module `A`. Then the process will end, losing anything you didn't write to disk.

```
$ python C.py
```

This will create a python process, load `C.py`, then `A.py`, and print the freshly loaded value from the dictionary of the newly read-in module `A`. This will be whatever was in the file `A.py`.